# Why default capture is not consistently const for both local variables and member variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I'm curious what's the story behind following inconsistency with passing default parameters:

```
struct Example {
    void run() {
        int localVar = 0;
        auto l = [=](){
            // localVar = 100; Not allowed (const copy of localVar)
            memberVar = 100; // allowed (const copy of this pointer - NOT const *this copy)
            };
        l();
    }
    int memberVar = 1;
};
```

Why not pass all parameters to lambda capture by const value (including const *this)?

Is that a desirable design choice, or result of a implementation limitation?

EDIT:

I know const pointer to the object is passed as a parameter and the object itself can be modified but the pointer itself cannot. But this is implementation detail that has to be known to the reader and is not obvious from the first look. Consistent from my subjective perspective would be capturing *this by const value...

Comment: `const`-ness is not transitive.  The `this` is const, the `*this` is not const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this is a lame behavior.

That's why in C++20 the implicit capture of `this` (i.e. by reference) is deprecated when the capture-default is `=`.

Presumably the intent is to change `=` one day to capture `*this` (i.e. by value).

Comment: I would presume / hope that intent is to change `=` to not capture `this` at all. `this` should be captured only by listing it explicitly. And if value capture of `*this` is desired, then capture `auto copy = *this`. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: @eerorika If that was the intent, `&` capturing `this` would also be deprecated.

Comment: I don't think `this` being captured by `&` is such a big problem as there is less room for confusion. But just because `this` being captured by `=` can be confusing doesn't mean that `*this` being captured by `=` couldn't also be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

> Why default capture is not consistently const for both local variables and member variables?

Because member variables aren't captured at all by a default capture. What is captured is `this` pointer. And that is "const": You cannot modify `this`. But in a non-const member function it is a pointer to non-const and thus you can modify the non-const members.